# How do i add LIGHTBOX to Attachments?

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, attachment

How do i add the light box function

> rel="lightbox"

to the code below

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_the_title($post->ID), 1 ) ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, 'large' ); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add rel="lightbox" in to the a href like this:

```
<a rel="lightbox" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_the_title($post->ID), 1 ) ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, 'large' ); ?></a>
```

Apart from that, I suggest you to go through the demo / tutorial / docs of the lightbox you're using. It also requires proper js and file to be included as well. And you need to initialize it using its simple jquery code too. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // Use this example, or...
    $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox(); // Select all links that contains lightbox in the attribute rel
    // This, or...
    $('#gallery a').lightBox(); // Select all links in object with gallery ID
    // This, or...
    $('a.lightbox').lightBox(); // Select all links with lightbox class
    // This, or...
    $('a').lightBox(); // Select all links in the page
    // ... The possibility are many. Use your creative or choose one in the examples above
});
</script>
```

You can refer to the docs for exact example of lightbox script.

Comment: What happens, can you share your page url?